# JSONP ajax call executes error method its response is 200 ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my api calling its response is 200 OK but it not entered into the success method I have no clue where i am doing wrong. I enable CORS on server side.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({

  url: 'https://localhost:44300/api/apim/{{Product.Id}}/'+email+'/',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
   alert("success");
    if(data===true){

        $('#subscribe').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#subscribe').text('Is Pending');
    }
    else 
    {

    }
  },
  error: function(err)
  {
  alert("Error");

  },
  type: 'GET'
 });
});
```

### Image

[image]

Comment: What does the response look like? Do you get any errors in the web console? What does the third argument to the error callback contain when it fails? (Your `err` argument name is a bit misleading: The first argument is a jqXHR object, the second is the HTTP status, and the third is the error message.)

Comment: true or false is the response

Comment: ?callback=jQuery19108204118995927274_1466501746321&_=1466501746322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said `dataType: 'jsonp',` but the server said `content-type: application/json`.

JSONP is `application/javascript` because it isn't JSON (it's a hack to get around the same origin policy from before we had CORS, since you are using CORS, it is pointless … well, you claim you are using CORS, but I don't see an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response).

Remove `dataType: 'jsonp'` and let jQuery work out the type of data from the content-type response header.